# How to implement a rich text editor such as Quill or Draft.js with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, quill, draftjs

I have a big application that I'm building with Next.js for SEO and performance purposes, and there's a super interactive part of this application that needs a Text Editor (such as Quill.js or Draft.js) where data in it is synced between two users using Socket.io.

The problem is I can't get a Text Editor to work with Next.js.

When I import Quill, it says 'Document is not defined' because there's no document on the server. With Draft.js, it simply doesn't render anything but there's no errors.

Here's my code for Draft.js:

```
import { EditorState, convertToRaw, convertFromRaw } from 'draft-js'


class TextEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(props.contentState))
    }
  }
  static async getInitialProps ({ query, req }) {
    return { contentState: convertToRaw(EditorState.createEmpty().getCurrentContent()) }
  }
  render() {
    console.log('init',this.props.editorState);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Test Editor</h1>
        <Editor
          editorState={ this.props.editorState }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

Use sun editor. This one is really flexible and compatible with nextjs.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/suneditor-react
npm i suneditor suneditor-react

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css'; // Import Sun Editor's CSS File to the _app.js

const SunEditor = dynamic(() => import("suneditor-react"), { //besure to import dynamically
  ssr: false,
});

const MyComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> My Other Contents </p>
      <SunEditor />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks rahat just a tiny question how to get the image tags from sunEditor's string data and render into nextjs's Image component, please help 

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simply component is working with NextJS and React Hook Form

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Editor, EditorState, ContentState, convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";
import "draft-js/dist/Draft.css";

export { EditorState, ContentState };

interface PropTypes {
  name?: string;
  value?: string;
  onChange?: Function;
}

// Trick to fix issue with NextJS https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/universal/editor.js
const emptyContentState = convertFromRaw({
  entityMap: {},
  blocks: [
    {
      text: "",
      key: "foo",
      type: "unstyled",
      entityRanges: [],
    },
  ],
});

function RichTextEditor({ name, value, onChange }: PropTypes) {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    EditorState.createWithContent(emptyContentState)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setEditorState(
      EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText(value))
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <Editor
      editorKey={name}
      editorState={editorState}
      onChange={(editorState) => {
        setEditorState(editorState);

        onChange(editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText());
      }}
      userSelect="none"
      contentEditable={false}
    />
  );
}

export default RichTextEditor;
```

```
<Controller
 as={RichTextEditor}
 name="description"
 control={control}
 defaultValue=""
/>
```